# Sprite Sheet Sprite Addition

Tags: sprite, game-development, sprite-sheet, spritebatch

So i have this spritesheet here:
[image: Kenney CC0 SpriteSheet]

And as seen on the left, you have to “add” the individual sprite parts, how do i do this?

Answer (score 0):

I imagine there's a dedicated color (looks like pink) that should be treated not as a color but as transparency. So, you draw the first one without drawing any pixels that are pink (that is, leaving the background as is), then you draw the second one on top of it in a similar fashion, then the third and so on.

Comment: Is there any program which lets me do this easily